# How to convert a string in list of string to a list of int in Python?

Tags: python

So i have outputed lines from a txt file to a list to with a function and it looks like this

```
List = ['5 15 1', '18 18 5', '16 5 7', '12 18 9', '6 3 7', '20 18 15']
```

each element containing 3 numbers is a string and i would like to turn these elements into list of int.

here is the my function

```
with open("data.txt") as file:
    List = [line.strip() for line in file]
    print(List)
```

anyone can help please ?

Comment: So do you want a single list, or a list of lists? (i.e. `[5,15,1,18,18...]` or `[(5, 15, 1), (18, 18, 5), ...]`)?

Comment: `[[int(e) for e in s.split()] for s in ['5 15 1', '18 18 5', '16 5 7', '12 18 9', '6 3 7', '20 18 15']]`

Comment: i would like a list of list MatsLindh

Comment: Just Edited my question to have better help, thanks to those who already  helped

Answer (score 1):

```
res = list()
for s in List:
    res += [int(x) for x in s.split()]
```

If you want a list of list you could do like follows :

```
res = list()
for s in List:
    res.append([int(x) for x in s.split()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
>>>map(lambda x: map(int, x.split()), List)
[[5, 15, 1], [18, 18, 5], [16, 5, 7], [12, 18, 9], [6, 3, 7], [20, 18, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert it into a unique string, then re-convert it into a list:

```
my_string = " ".join(my_list)
my_list = my_string.split(" ")
```

This is for a list of ints, for a list of lists you can do instead:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(my_list))
    new_list.append(my_list[i].split(" "))
```